# Variance-covariance matrix of the residuals of an object of class merMod (R package lme4)

Tags: lme4-nlme

I am trying to extract the variance-covariance matrix of the residuals of a generalized linear mixed-effects model that was fitted using lmer (of the R package lme4), but this does not seem to be straightforward. Does anybody knows how this can be done?

Thanks,

Regards,
Willem

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how to do something in R. It would be better to ask this on a list devoted to R or lme.

Answer (score 1):

As stated [here](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/mult_pkg/glmm.htm), we usually do not need to estimate the variance-covariance matrix of the error term (or residuals, in the sense of latent outcome) in generalized linear mixed models:

> The variance-covariance matrix of the residuals, $ε$ or the condition
>   covariance matrix of $y|X\beta+Z\gamma$. The most common residual
>   covariance structure is
>
> $$R=I\sigma^2_ε$$ where $I$ is the identity matrix (diagonal matrix of
>   1s) and $\sigma^2_ε$ is the residual variance. This structure assumes
>   a homogeneous residual variance for all (conditional) observations and
>   that they are (conditionally) independent. Other structures can be
>   assumed such as compound symmetry or autoregressive.

Take binary data for an example, for logit link function, $\sigma^2_ε=\pi^2/3$ as the error comes for standard logistic distribution; for probit link, $\sigma^2_ε=1$ as the error comes from standard normal distribution.